# Angular2 doesn't recognize a module on npm start

Tags: typescript, angular

I have installed a new module, added it to my system js config:

```
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'angular2-notifications': 'node_modules/angular2-notifications',
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'angular2-notifications': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
  };
```

imported it in my component

```
import {NotificationsService, SimpleNotificationsComponent} from 'angular2-notifications'
```

and I get this error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'notifications'.
```

Which refered to the import statement above.

The module works if I delete any reference of it, starting my app, Adding the imports and directives again after my app is already running, and the module works fine.

Why do I get this error on `npm start` while when the app is running I get no error and everything works as excepted?

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript compiler runs before SystemJS, so it (tsc) has no knowledge of your SystemJS configuration. You must still refer to the node module by the name it gets installed as:

```
import {NotificationsService, SimpleNotificationsComponent}
  from 'angular2-notifications';
```

Comment: If I'm changing it to angular2-notificaiton it can't find the right folder. Changing it in the system js config too from `notificaitons` to `angular2-notificaitons` returns the same , `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2-notifications'.`

Answer (score 0):

This is probelm with the npm packages i'm using
https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications/issues/25